# Git prompt for username in Jenkins agent

Tags: git, jenkins, github, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline

Is there a way to pass git credentials to a Jenkins agent?

I'm running Jenkins in Kubernetes and have an agent defined via a pod template to carry out specific builds.

My challenge is that the build keeps on failing with this error `fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address

I have exec'd into the agent to dig a little deeper and it turns out that when the `git push` command is executed within the pipeline, it's prompted to enter a username `Username for 'https://github.com':`

How can credentials be passed into the agent so it just uses it without prompting?

I've looked at this https://github.com/github/hub/issues/1644 and tried to configure the credential helper as explained [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store) but I'm still getting the prompt.

One issue with the credential helper seems to be that you still have to enter your username and password at least once, which I can't do as it's running in automation.

I'd go with ssh but unfortunately, it's not an option at the moment.

Anyone with any ideas please?

Comment: A Jenkins job would typically get the credentials it needs from the [Jenkins credentials store](https://github.com/jenkinsci/credentials-plugin/blob/master/docs/user.adoc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you need to store your credentials (GitHub username and Token) in the Credentials store and use them by `withCredentials` block.

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(
  credentialsId: 'MY_GITHUB_USERNAME_PASSWORD_CREDENTIALS',
  passwordVariable: 'TOKEN',
  usernameVariable: 'USER')]) {
  sh "git push https://${USER}:${TOKEN}@github.com/mycompany/myrepo.git mybranch -f"
}
```

In case you want to use [SSH Agent plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ssh-agent/), you can use `ssh` authentication instead of `https`. After you add your public key to your GitHub user, this may look like this:

```
sshagent(credentials: ['MY_GITHUB_SSH_CREDENTIALS']) {
    sh "git push git@github.com:mycompany/myrepo.git mybranch -f")
}
```

Comment: This does the job for me. Thanks a lot MaratC